# Windows Media Player will not play videos from a mapped folder

Tags: windows-media-player, mapped-drive

I have encountered a strange problem with Windows Media Player (which seems, of all Microsoft programs, to have many strange problems).

> I have a folder, specifically `%userprofile%\Documents\Temporary` mapped as drive `I:` using subst, for convenience. This way commonly used folders look like network drives and I don't have to navigate through `%userprofile%` to find stuff. I have actual mapped drives as well but that's not relevant here.

I just imported some videos to `I:\Payphone` which is the same as `%userprofile%\Documents\Temporary\Payphone`. When double clicking a video from I:\Payphone, I see:

[image]

When trying to open a video from `%userprofile%\Documents\Temporary\Payphone`, the video opens normally without issue.

[image]

Strangely enough, I copied the folders to a share on a fileserver and tried opening one:

[image]

So when I open a video from a mapped drive on a *different* computer, it works. When I open a video from a mapped drive on *my* computer, it fails! This makes absolutely no sense! They are the exact same video, in the exact same directory, just being accessed in slightly different ways.

I **do NOT** want to have to navigate to `%userprofile%\Documents\Temporary\Payphone`. How can I force WMP to open videos from `I:\Payphone`?

Comment: @Biswapriyo .MOV, but I don't think the encoding is the issue. No problem opening from one path, it's only the subst path that fails

Comment: Can any other player like VLC open that file where WMP can't?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I knew I would be hearing that... would rather not install VLC unless absolutely necessary. I like WMP much better (when it works) and this computer is slow enough as it is

Comment: @Biswapriyo Works just fine with VLC, as expected. I suppose now that I have it, I may as well use it. But that doesn't answer my question as to what was wrong to begin with.